# Android Keystore 'Cannot recover key' for Alias Password

Tags: android, android-studio, alias, keystore, android-app-bundle

I'm trying to publish an update to an Android app that was originally published to the store back in 2014. I still have the Keystore file, but none of the development environment (e.g. Eclipse).

I originally thought I forgot the Keystore password, but then remembered that that password was empty. But yet, Android Studio won't let me use a Keystore with an empty password. So I needed to do a good bit of research to find information on how I could change this... I finally came across https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/forgot-keystore-passwordjks-file-you-can-still-recover-it which gave an example of changing from a blank password.

Once I changed this password, I was then able to get past the 'Password verification failed' message I was receiving when generating a signed app bundle through Android Studio.

The problem is now that I received the 'Cannot recover key' message when generating a signed app bundle. Doing research, this seems to be when the alias key password has been input incorrectly. I was nearly positive that I was using the correct password (the same one that I changed the Keystore password above to) but yet it won't let me. Is there any way to overcome this? As I said above, I don't have access to the gradle or logs from the development environment... and I really don't want to have to upload a new app to the store.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you try opening both keystore files you have (the one with empty password and the one with the password) with [Keystore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/).

Note that there are two sets of passwords usually with a '*.jks' file format keystore, one for the keystore having your keys or aliases, and another for unlocking a key or an alias inside the keystore, they can be different and you need to have both when signing. So also try unlocking the key or the alias in the keystore by right clicking on it and selecting "unlock" inside Keystore Expolrer.

Getting the right passwords will then let you make amends such as re-setting the password of the keystore, re-setting the password of a key or alias, or even create a new keystore completely and copy the key or alias into it, just make sure to save a copy with backups every step of the way so not to lose your key(s).

Comment: Hi @ahasbini, thanks for this. I've downloaded the tool and I was able to brute-force my unlocking password and for some reason, I remembered my old password. So I appreciate this. Thank you. For others, it seems like that if you forget either password, there is no way around it.... so I'm now emailing myself the keystore file and details so I have them if anything ever happens.